# gradle properties: how not to escape values that will be used as environment variables?

Tags: gradle, docker-compose, properties

gradle properties:  how not to escape values that will be used as environment variables?

```
task foo(type: Properties) {
    property "foo", "a=b"
}
```

The generated properties file:

```
foo=a\=b
```

When the properties file is used as environment variables (e.g., docker-compose .env file)

the foo value is `a\=b`, not `a=b`.